# Reporting Services TempDB keeps going into restoring mode

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2008

I am looking into an issue with SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services. It has been working fine until yesterday morning. Now I notice that `ReportServerTempDB` keeps on going into `Restoring...` mode. I restored it to online mode with `RESTORE DATABASE [ReportServerQ4TempDB] WITH RECOVERY`.

The reports work fine after this and then after 10-15 minutes, then `ReportServerTempDB` goes back into Restoring mode. Report execution gives the following error:

> An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. (rsReportServerDatabaseError)
>   For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors...

Any suggestions why it is doing that.

I have checked the following

1. Memory - 50% available
2. CPU - only 10% utilized
3. Storage - 30% space remaining

There are multiple instance of SSRS running and SQL instance hosting the database for SSRS on the same server.

I have checked that AutoClose is not enabled for this database, and I have discovered that the database goes into `Restoring...` mode every hour, when our log backup job runs.

[image]

Comment: please show us exactly the command that the hourly log backup job is sending to SQL Server. Maybe it's also doing a restore without your knowledge.

Comment: What is the backup solution that you're using?

Comment: ...and why is ReportServerTempDB in full recovery mode, and why are you performing log backups? You should consider switching it to simple and removing it from the log backup maintenance.

Comment: Also are you using log shipping on this instance? Any chance someone thought it would be a good idea to have ReportServerTempDB participate in log shipping, and the timing of the log shipping happens to coincide with your local log backups?

Comment: TO answer all the above <br>
We are using SQL Maintenance Plans to take log backups
In regards to taking backups... These were setup by previous DBA so I am going to find why it was setup that way.. But the log backups should still work in theory.
---

Comment: Also I turned off Verify backup for T-Logs and that seems to have resolved. I have a feeling that the disk might be having issues. I ran DBCC check and didn't find anything on the databases.

Comment: Verify backup should not cause a database to go into `Restoring...`

Comment: What was the result of this query?  `SELECT name, recovery_model_desc
        FROM sys.databases where name = N'ReportServerQA5TempDB'`

Comment: @swasheck - The recovery model is Full for the database. I suspect something else is going on. Ever since I turned off verify backup, the issue has not occurred.

Comment: Have you tried changing it back to `SIMPLE` and observing this behavior?

Comment: @swasheck I haven't given a try. Let me test

Comment: @swasheck - I have changed it to Simple and turned verify on, everything is fine. Now I changed it back to full and kept verify on... DB is still online. At this point, I feel like there was something got reset after changes were made and now everything is working fine. I have checked event logs and do not find anything

Comment: @Rizwan PLEASE keep it in Simple. You don't need this database to be in Full recovery mode.

Comment: I agree.... I am changing it to Simple now. Hopefully won't see the issue again.

I want to thank @swasheck, Aaron Bertrand, mrdenny for taking your time to help me with this. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you running a log backup job on `[ReportServerQA5TempDB]`? It *should* be in simple mode.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159093.aspx):

> ReportServerTempdb is created with the primary report server database and is used to store temporary data, session information, and cached reports.

[and](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155814.aspx)

> Use the simple recovery model to backup the reportservertempdb database.

Now the real question becomes, "What are you using for your backups?" Check to make sure that it's not changing the recovery model and that ReportServerTempDB is still in `SIMPLE` recovery model.

```
    SELECT name, recovery_model_desc
        FROM sys.databases;
```

I wonder if your solution is trying to switch back and forth between recovery models and is failing somewhere along the way. I have a vague recollection of this having happened to me in the past.

Try changing the recovery model to Simple and removing it from your hourly log backup job.

```
ALTER DATABASE ReportServerQA5TempDB SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
```